# can't figure out why ajax json request to server fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am learning how to make an ajax request with jquery and json. I have the following code:

**jquery**

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('submit','#form', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var nombre = $("#nombre").val();
         var apellido = $("#apellido").val();
         alert(nombre+apellido);
         sendajax(nombre,apellido);
        });
        
        function sendajax(nombre,apellido){
                $.ajax({
                        data:  {
                            "nombre": nombre,
                            "apellido": apellido
                        },
                        contentType:"application/json",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url:   'ajax/ajax.php',
                        type:  'post'
                })
                .done (function(response) {
           alert(response.nombre);
             })
             .fail (function() {
                 alert("failed");
             });
        }
       });
```

```
**ajax.php**
```

```js
if(isset($_POST['nombre'])){
 $json_data = array ('nombre' => $_POST['nombre'] , 'apellido' => $_POST['apellido']);
 header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
 echo json_encode(json_data);
}
```

As you can see I'm not passing the inputs values from the form, I am just expecting an alert with the string "nombre" (only for testing purposes). But the request keeps failing and i can't figure out why. Something wrong in my code?

Comment: I don't know if this has to do with your problem, but it should probably read `echo json_encode($json_data)` in `ajax.php`.

Comment: and you should check for both keys (nombre and apellido) with isset before using them.

Comment: Remove the `contentType` setting from `$.ajax`, you're not sending JSON, but `x-www-form-urlencoded`, as that's what jQuery defaults to.